# Is there a easy way to add a save game menu to a adobe director game

Tags: lingo

Is there a easy way to add a save game menu to a adobe director game, without using FileIO Xtra  so the player can play the game where they left off.

And this is a point & click game where there  progress changes as they play the game.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  Check out `setPref` and `getPref` in the manual.

You could read the point where they left off on app startup and save it just before closing the game. Some global variable or an object can be used to keep track of the game progress.

(Of course you need to be able to modify the code.)